# set_xlim() sets the wrong date range

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to explicitly set the `xlim` range, my X axis uses `datetime` dates.

When I explicitly set the range, `matplotlib` seems to automatically adjust it:

```
axA.set_xlim([mdates.num2date(736299.0), mdates.num2date(736724.0)])
print(axA.get_xlim())

output >> (17136.0, 17561.0)
```

Why is the value returned different than what I set it to?

I'm trying to set xlim and draw a vertical line at particular point. Full example reproducing the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime


def get_dataframe():
    values = [11, 22, 11]
    dates = [
        datetime(2017, 12, 1),
        datetime(2017, 12, 2),
        datetime(2017, 12, 3)
    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': dates, 'value': values})
    df = df.set_index(['date']).sort_index()

    return df


def plot(dataA):
    fig, axA = plt.subplots()
    dataA.plot(ax=axA)

    # same result whether I try to set with numbers or datetime objects
    # axA.set_xlim([datetime(2016, 12, 1), datetime(2018, 1, 30)])
    axA.set_xlim([mdates.num2date(736299.0), mdates.num2date(736724.0)])
    print(axA.get_xlim())

    # trying to draw a line at a X date in range
    axA.axvline(736614.0)
    axA.axvline(mdates.datestr2num('2017-10-12'))


df = get_dataframe()
plot(df)
plt.show()
```

*I've been stuck on this for over a day now, Googling and searching SO extensively; any help or pointers in the right direction or the right docs would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Python 3.6.3 and matplotlib 2.1.1*

Comment: I'm not actually able to reproduce this if you use straight numbers  (only using datetimes). I'm using Python 3.6.3 on Ubuntu and Matplotlib 2.0.0. There might be a commit in the last minor release of Matplotlib that changed this behavior.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Thanks for taking the time to check. I tried downgrading to `2.0.0` but get the same problem: `$ pip freeze | grep matplotlib ; python /tmp/test.py >> matplotlib==2.0.0 >> (17136.0, 17561.0)`. It seems you can reproduce it with the `datetime`s though, so that is the same issue as I would assume we should be able to set the `xlim` with `datetime`s